# Will I be able to do a New Game+ regardless of the decisions I make at the end of the game?

Tags: bastion

At the end of Bastion, I'm granted two choices. I'm worried that if I make the wrong decisions, I won't be able to start up a New Game+, something which I definitely want to do. The reason I'm worried about this is because...

> ...the choices are between choosing to reincarnate the world and choosing to simply leave it, destroying the ability to reincarnate it. This seems like a choice between seeing the actual ending of the game and choosing to hold off on it for another playthrough.

Regardless of the choices I make during the endgame, will I still be able to do a New Game+?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, either choice will let you do a New Game+. The outcome of the first play through has no bearing on the second play through.

Comment: New Game Plus continues the plot of the Restoration ending.  You don't actually have to pick Restoration, but New Game Plus just shows you what would have happened if you had.  There is no plot written in the game for what happens after the Evacuation ending (this could be sequel material but there don't seem to be any plans for a sequel).